# ‎Jointly ‎continuous of product in $B(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

‎Let ‎$‎B(H)‎$ ‎be the set of‎ ‎bounded ‎operators ‎on a Hilbert space ‎‎$‎‎H$.‎

‎
I ‎know that ‎$u_{‎\alpha‎}‎\longrightarrow u‎$‎‎‎ ‎in ‎S.O.T ‎if ‎and ‎only ‎if‎  ‎$u_{‎\alpha‎}(x)‎\longrightarrow u(x)‎$ for all‎$‎‎x\in H$.‎

‎
 I know that 
‎$\cdot : ‎‎B(H)‎\times B(H) ‎\longrightarrow ‎B(H)‎$‎‎‎ ‎such ‎that ‎‎$‎‎(u,v)‎\longmapsto uv‎$‎‎ ‎is ‎separately ‎continuous ‎and ‎jointly ‎continuous ‎on ‎bounded ‎set.

‎
 ‎
 Q:I ‎need some ‎nets ‎or ‎sequences ‎in ‎‎$‎B(H)‎$ ‎such ‎that ‎product ‎is ‎not ‎jointly ‎continuous ‎i.e I‎ ‎need ‎‎$(u_{‎\alpha‎}) $‎ ‎and‎$‎ (‎v‎_{‎\alpha‎}‎)$ in $B(H)$ ‎such ‎that ‎ ‎‎$u_{‎\alpha‎}‎\longrightarrow u‎$ and ‎$v_{‎\alpha‎}‎\longrightarrow u‎$ in S.O.T topology but ‎$u_{‎\alpha‎}v_{‎\alpha‎}‎\nrightarrow‎ uv‎$

Answer (score 1):

Let $I$ be the directed set of finite dimensional subspaces of $H$, ordered with inclusion. Define for such a subspace $u_V = 0\cdot \pi_V +\, 2^{|V|}\cdot\pi_{V^\perp}$, here $\pi$ is the projection onto the subspace in the index and $|V|$ the dimension of $V$. This (unbounded) net converges to zero in the strong topology, as $u_V$ restricted to $V$ is zero.

For a general definition of $v_V$ we need the axiom of choice, but for most specific Hilbert space it is probably possible to do this without choice, we'll see that for $\ell^2(\Bbb N)$, and since for most Hilbert spaces you consider you have explicit isomorphisms to $\ell^2(\Bbb N)$ it works without choice for those too.

For any finite dimensional subspace $V$ choose a norm $1$ element $x_V$ from $V^\perp$. Further choose an arbitrary norm one element of $H$, $x$ (this element does not depend on $V$). Let $v_V(x)=\frac{x_V\otimes x^*}{|V|}$, ie the map that sends $x$ to $x_V$ with scaling $\frac1{|V|}$ and zero on the complement. This net converges to $0$ in norm and thus also in the strong operator topology.

Now $\|u_Vv_V(x)\| = \left\|\frac{2^{|V|}}{|V|}x_V\right\|=\frac{2^{|V|}}{|V|}$, so $u_Vv_V$ does not converge to zero in SOT.

To get rid of choice in $\ell^2(\Bbb N)$, let $(e_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be the standard Hilbert basis, let $x_V$ be the first non-zero $\pi_{V^\perp} e_n$ (rescaled to norm one) and $x$ be $e_1$.

Comment: I think the assertion that $|x_k|^2$ is eventually smaller than $\frac{1}{k}$ is false. I think the whole argument cannot hold since the sequence $u_n$ is not bounded in norm which must be the case by the uniform boundedness principle.

Comment: You are right about that part of the argument not working. My error was a basic one: I thought since $\frac1k$ is not absolutely summable the quotient of anything absolutely summable with it must converge to zero. This is not true.

Comment: I will try to construct a working example.

Comment: Good luck! You will need to find an example that is a net, that's all I can contribute

Comment: Yes, I have understood your remark about uniform boundedness now, which rules sequences out.

Comment: Glad I could help with this

Comment: Alright, I think I have constructed a working example.