# Show that $S_n \to S $(weakly) and $T_n \to T$ strongly implies $S_nT_n \to ST$ weakly

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, weak-convergence, strong-convergence

Let $X,Y,Z$ be Banach Spaces. Let $T_n,T \subset BL(X,Y), S_n,S \in  BL(Y,Z)$. Show that

a) $S_n \to S $(weakly) and $T_n \to T$ (strongly) implies $S_nT_n \to ST$ (weakly)

b) $S_n \to S $(uniformly) and $T_n \to T$ (weakly) implies $S_nT_n \to ST$ (weakly)

c)$S_n \to S $(weakly) and $T_n \to T$ (uniformly) doesn't necessarily imply $S_nT_n \to ST$ (strongly)

d)$S_n \to S $(strongly) and $T_n \to T$ (weakly) doesn't necessarily imply that $S_nT_n \to ST$ (weakly)

My try:

a) Since I need to show that for all $f \in BL(Z,K), f(S_nT_nx) \to f(STx)$, I add $f\circ S_n(Tx)$ and subtract it to get $$|f(S_nT_nx) - f(STx)|\le ||f||||S_n||||T_nx-Tx||+||f\circ S_n(Tx)-f\circ S(Tx)||$$

For a fixed $x$, Let $E=\{S_nx: n \ge 1\}$. Now $f(E)$ is bounded for all $f\in BL(Z,K)$. B Resonance theorem $E$ is bounded. Hence by Uniform Boundedness Principle $\sup_{n}||S_n|| \lt \infty$. Hence the first thing goes to zero as $T_nx \to Tx $ (strongly) and the second thing too by the weak convergence of $S_n$ to $S$.

b) $$||(f\circ S_n)(T_n(x)-(fos)(Tx)||\le ||f||||S_n-S||||T_n(x)||+||(f\circ S)(T_n(x)-T(x))||$$

Again I will use Resonance Theorem to conclude that $T_n(x)$ is bounded for each $x$ and Uniform Boundedness Principle to conclude that $\sup_{n}||T_n|| \lt \infty$ and that would make the first term to go to $0$. The second term goes to $0$ because $f\circ S \in BL(Y,K)$ and weak convergence of $T_n$.

Is this alright??

I am unable to find counterexamples for (c) and (d).

Comment: To clarify the terminology, "weakly" refers to the weak operator topology, "strongly" to the strong operator topology and "uniformly" to the norm topology?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes

Comment: Assuming that the resonance theorem (never heard that name) says that a weakly bounded set is norm-bounded, your arguments for a) and b) are correct.

Comment: @DanielFischer :). Yeah!! Okay!! It is a name that my instructor picked (who taught Functional Analysis). The name can be found in Yoshida's book as well.

Comment: Note that strong convergence implies weak convergence, uniform convergence implies strong convergence. So c) and d) can both be gotten by sequences $S_n$ strongly convergent to $S$, $T_n$ uniformly convergent to $T$ so that $S_n T_n$ converge  uniformly to something that is _not_ $ST$. An example of that is here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1634361/jointly-continuous-of-product-in-bh/1634403#1634403

Comment: Sorry I think I am a little confused, strong implies weak in the Hilbert space case. Also the counter example should then also be a counter-example for a), which is a true statement. But the counter example also looks true..

Comment: @harp I am not seeing how the link is an example

Comment: In the link $u_n \to (1-\pi_0)$ strongly, $v_n \to 0$ uniformly, $u_n v_n \to \pi_0$ uniformly, but $(1-\pi_0)\, 0 = 0 \neq \pi_0$